# Map a Matrix to a Circular Frame Image

Tags: plot

I have a matrix and o want to map it to a circular frame. Each element in matrix should be mapped to a predefined position on the circular frame. What i am really do is dealing with the human brain signals recorded from different electrodes installed over the skull. This is the final plot i want to get:
http://www.ihr.mrc.ac.uk/img/research/2009/3/scan-banner.jpg

Any Sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct me if I'm wrong. I don't know what kind of data these electrodes are able to retrieve, but in any case, I think you can view them in two different natures: first, sampled data (a class that encapsulates all information gathered through one specific electrode) and second, a geographically mapping object, binding the data from each electrode to one specific location.

As for the first part, you can design whatever class you wish, according to your needs. This class may have but a single double value (like intensity or electric level, or whatever) or a complete set of variables or even other classes arranged in such a way that represent what you need.

As for the second part, as you want to map the data retrieved from each electrode into a pre-determined point in a circular area, I think a class having an horizontal and a vertical positioning value is good. This can be a java.awt.Point (which can map to the real X and Y position of the point you wish) or a custom class (non-related to any domain) with the two X and Y variables, that can translate to a real X and Y coordinate in the final image.

Something like that

```
public class Position {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Sample {
    private double electricalLevel;
    private Position position;
    public double getElectricalLevel() {
        return electricalLevel;
    }
    public void setElectricalLevel(double electricalLevel) {
        this.electricalLevel = electricalLevel;
    }
    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Something like that.

Then you'll have to instantiate each Sample, map it to a Position instance and keep updating the values.

As for the mapping to the correct Position, you can have all the positions pre-calculated and entered as literals, or calculated from a positioning function. I think the pre-calculated positions are ok, as they are not prone to changing...

Then you'll have something like:

```
Sample s1 = new Sample();
s1.setPosition(new Position(100, 100));

Sample s2 = new Sample();
s2.setPosition(new Position(150, 80));
```

and so on, for each electrode.

As for the drawing itself, you'll have to dig into java imaging. This will not be so simple, because you're not really only plotting the points themselves. Actually, the colour of each point and its surrounding area will be a function of the sampled data, if I'm correct, as the colour seems to be reflecting the sampled data from that brain region.

To make things worse, the boundary areas between multiple points will influence each other, so that a colour gradient will be generated.

I suggest you first focus in the given scenario and that you ask about the painting and java imaging issue in other question.

Sorry, this is a really general answer, but it's as far as I can go with many assumptions and without knowing what exactly you're dealing with. I hope it helps, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What i really looking for is a toolkit or function which can do the whole task or at least half of it! All i want is that after using the imshow in a square frame, just reshape it to a circular one, since the electrodes distributed uniformly, the final positions in the circular is OK for me.